# Cannot read property '_createInstanceCore' of null error in Breeze since "Datatype" is null for ComplexType

Tags: rest, merge, breeze, complextype

I am trying to create the Array complex Type  in breeze,since the Complex Type dataType is coming as 'null'  ,the following code triggers exception

```
if (prop.isScalar) {
                        val = prop.dataType._createInstanceCore(entity, prop);
                    } else {
                        val = breeze.makeComplexArray([], entity, prop);
                    }
```

Please help me to populate the 'dataType' property of Complex Type.

Entities Used:

```
"dataProperties": [
    {
        "name": "carriers",
        "complexTypeName":"Carrier#Test",
        "isScalar":false
    }]
```

The Carrier entity is defined as below:

```
 {
    "shortName": "Carrier",
    "namespace": "Test",
    "isComplexType": true,
    "dataProperties": [
        {
            "name": "Testing",
            "dataType": "String"
        }
    ]
    }
```

Comment: Going to need more than a few one liners to help.  How did you generate metadata?  Server or client?  Are you getting results back from server or generating something client-side?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26556150/datatype-of-complextype-entity-is-null-when-returning-an-array-of-complex-types

This ticket has the entities used. Please give some ideas to fix the issue

Comment: I'm having the same issue here...