# datatype of complextype entity is null when returning an array of complex types

Tags: rest, merge, breeze, complextype

We have created a complextype field "carriers" which is an array of Carrier objects. See below metadata

```
"dataProperties": [
    {
        "name": "carriers",
        "complexTypeName":"Carrier#Test",
        "isScalar":false
    }]
```

The Carrier entity is defined as below:

```
 {
    "shortName": "Carrier",
    "namespace": "Test",
    "isComplexType": true,
    "dataProperties": [
        {
            "name": "Testing",
            "isScalar":true,
            "dataType": "String"
        }
    ]
    }
```

We are trying to return an array of complextype in breeze from a REST service call. We get an error in breeze.debug.js in the method proto._updateTargetFromRaw. The error is because the datatype is null.

Any idea how to fix this issue?

Comment: Sorry, we need a little more information than that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing the problem is in your "complexTypeName". You wrote "Carrier#Test" when I think you meant to write "Carrier:#Test".  The ":#" combination separates the "short name" from the namespace; you omitted the colon.

Hope that's the explanation.